# Cryptography on programming

Tags: algorithm-design, reference-request

In pursuit of understanding a randomly found topic I was interested in learning the connection between integer programming and cryptography and found Lenstra Jr.'s [Integer Programming and Cryptography](https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~hwl/PUBLICATIONS/1984f/art.pdf). It is bit technical for my taste. Is there an easier reference to use for a novice to learn about what cryptography and linear/integer programming has to do with one another. And what are the ongoing works in this field ?
Appreciate your time in answering this question.

Answer (score 2):

It's Hendrik Lenstra [to distinguish from Arjen Lenstra, both have worked on cryptography].

And, I am afraid I don't know how much the technical details in that article can be omitted, in the sense that only notation is defined and straightforward relationships are explored.

For example, clearly, a knapsack problem is exactly equivalent to an integer linear program.

And the problem finding integral points within a set, as on page 15, if one exists, is related to problems in more recent cryptographic structures such as those used in lattice based cryptography.